# Substrate node-template private network WITHOUT using default keys

Tags: blockchain, substrate

I'm trying to build a 5 node network (all validators and members of Aura & GRANPA) and my goal is to **use custom keys**, not the predefined Alice, etc. Thus added the SR and ED authority keys in the custom spec JSON file. The node-template version is an unchanged V3 from Github.

I followed the tutorial (https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/customchain) but this error shows up:

```
2021-07-26 09:17:35 Substrate Node
2021-07-26 09:17:35 ✌️ version 3.0.0-unknown-x86_64-linux-gnu
2021-07-26 09:17:35 ❤️ by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2021
2021-07-26 09:17:35  Chain specification: The Batman Chain
2021-07-26 09:17:35  Node name: Node1
2021-07-26 09:17:35  Role: AUTHORITY
2021-07-26 09:17:35  Database: RocksDb at /peer-data-1/chains/TBC_testnet/db
2021-07-26 09:17:35 ⛓ Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
2021-07-26 09:17:36  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x531c…653b, header-hash: 0x4c1f…570d)
2021-07-26 09:17:36  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.
2021-07-26 09:17:36 ⏱ Loaded block-time = 6000 milliseconds from genesis on first-launch
2021-07-26 09:17:36 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2021-07-26 09:17:36  Local node identity is: 12D3KooWRzP2WuCbHENdXkf5ZvBStmgYn2N8mkwPofQparf58tkF
2021-07-26 09:17:36  Highest known block at #0
2021-07-26 09:17:36 〽️ Prometheus server started at 0.0.0.0:9615
2021-07-26 09:17:36 Listening for new connections on 0.0.0.0:9944.
2021-07-26 09:17:37  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/10.42.0.82/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWRzP2WuCbHENdXkf5ZvBStmgYn2N8mkwPofQparf58tkF
2021-07-26 09:17:37 GRANDPA voter error: Signing("Failed to sign GRANDPA vote for round 1 targetting 0x4c1f6404ff3236cbd58fa62dffe9b8e2b2ac670f06516541a641158c0a0a570d")
2021-07-26 09:17:37 Essential task `grandpa-voter` failed. Shutting down service.
Error: Service(Other("Essential task failed."))
```

To start the node I use this command:

```sh
node-template key insert \
    --base-path /peer-data-1 \
    --chain local \
    --key-type aura \
    --suri "0x0e32f2687f1234deb25e20a50c39db5cdf0a2f2ccb84995189522fc9f20beb37";

node-template key insert \
    --base-path /peer-data-1 \
    --chain local \
    --key-type gran \
    --suri "0x0e32f2687f1234deb25e20a50c39db5cdf0a2f2ccb84995189522fc9f20beb37";
ls -l /peer-data-1/chains/local_testnet/keystore;

RUST_LOG=runtime=debug
node-template \
    --base-path /peer-data-1 \
    --name Node1 \
    --node-key 0x0e32f2687f1234deb25e20a50c39db5cdf0a2f2ccb84995189522fc9f20beb37 \
    --chain /genesis/customSpecRaw.json \
    --keystore-path /peer-data-1/chains/local_testnet/keystore/ \
    --port 30333 \
    --ws-port 9944 \
    --rpc-port 9933 \
    --unsafe-ws-external \
    --unsafe-rpc-external \
    --rpc-cors=all \
    --prometheus-external \
    --log info \
    --wasm-execution Compiled \
    --ws-max-connections 1000 \
    --pool-limit 10000 \
    --pool-kbytes 20480 \
    --max-runtime-instances 100 \
    --validator \
    --bootnodes /ip4/$SUBSTRATE_0_SERVICE_HOST/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp
```

Custom spec JSON file is:

```json
{
 "...": "...",
 "palletAura": {
        "authorities": [
          "5HVmrhNjMCfqRmjfcWTeEhgLMm1mgG9wAeQtKv1jZsUXrJjR",
          "5ChaeMbZEqvCYkh6ZZudYEPdwqApTCQzhbUPyX6Hxs5VX6yd",
          "5DB3vFrmvn49dpwzczYtFqxbfgn5U7DV8AHkkWFBcp3tWxwG",
          "5GT9aamoicKpUNRkWzQs83kLzufWZGt7aHX8ZWaAxKLmBdCW",
          "5CeaUtvsDQJHmuS1PJPns9kNuYEYCZdJE4ze8tdXSzgZkd4a"
        ]
      },
      "palletGrandpa": {
        "authorities": [
          [
            "5DvLRumQ8R9uSqV5xPmDsFBwQfjZCHzh6ebT5wqmARVRo9XE",
            1
          ],
          [
            "5CvYJbuiAyeGiBiPUtDp1Y5u3547f5AVai6qSXQBanR1j9m9",
            1
          ],
          [
            "5DPmV9GaQke2jUb7DmtRaf7fmrEX4aWSwzPzUsPtUNZUnYhU",
            1
          ],
          [
            "5FvcixYnySyxCEpv5QRQ9vj3h6QUH3ogpnXjGc4x4NahSXhH",
            1
          ],
          [
            "5CCuMSKoa13eeyKShzsNyGKMk5iicgnQn19zach8D2yznWgz",
            1
          ]
        ]
      },
   "...": "...",
}
```

Comment: i'd like to point out that the genesis changed a bit in substrate 4. in 4.x substrate it's `aura` and not `palletAura`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

- I reversed the aura and grandpa authorities IDs. Make sure **AURA uses Sr25519 ss58 Addresses** and **grandpa uses Ed25519 ss58 Addresses**.
- The code to start the node was wrong, I added *--scheme Ed25519/Sr25519* to make sure key added in keystore is OK.

```
node-template key insert \
    --base-path /peer-data-1 \
    --chain local \
    --key-type aura \
    --scheme Sr25519 \
    --suri "0x0e32f2687f1234deb25e20a50c39db5cdf0a2f2ccb84995189522fc9f20beb37";
node-template key insert \
    --base-path /peer-data-1 \
    --chain local \
    --key-type gran \
    --scheme Ed25519 \
    --suri "0x0e32f2687f1234deb25e20a50c39db5cdf0a2f2ccb84995189522fc9f20beb37";
ls -l /peer-data-1/chains/local_testnet/keystore;
RUST_LOG=runtime=debug
node-template \
    --base-path /peer-data-1 \
    --name Node1 \
    --chain /genesis/customSpecRaw.json \
    --keystore-path /peer-data-1/chains/local_testnet/keystore/ \
    --node-key 0x0e32f2687f1234deb25e20a50c39db5cdf0a2f2ccb84995189522fc9f20beb37 \
    --port 30333 \
    --ws-port 9944 \
    --rpc-port 9933 \
    --unsafe-ws-external \
    --unsafe-rpc-external \
    --rpc-cors=all \
    --prometheus-external \
    --log info \
    --wasm-execution Compiled \
    --ws-max-connections 1000 \
    --pool-limit 10000 \
    --pool-kbytes 20480 \
    --max-runtime-instances 100 \
    --validator \
    --bootnodes /ip4/$SUBSTRATE_0_SERVICE_HOST/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp
```

Comment: Where the suri come from?